# Process.exit(pid, :not_kill_reason) doesn't call handle_info({:EXIT, pid, reason},state)

Tags: elixir

EDIT: I was totally wrong.. this GenServer Example doesn't make sense since the real code is a little bit more complex (a GenServer that starts GenServers that runs tasks etc..), It turns out i was exiting the wrong process and messed it up with the logs. Sorry.

I have a GenServer with an exit trap.. If I call `Process.exit(pid, :kill)` the callback handle_info **is called**, but if it is another reason the callback is **never called**

Simplified GenServer

```
defmodule Example do
  use GenServer

  def start(args, opts \\ []) do
    GenServer.start(__MODULE__, args, opts)
  end

  def init({task, meta}) do
    Process.flag(:trap_exit, true)
  end

  def kill do
    Process.exit(self, :not_kill_reason)
  end

  def handle_info({:EXIT, pid, reason}, state) do
    IO.puts("handle_info, reason: #{reason}")
    {:stop, :normal, nil}
  end
end
```

I think I'm missing something, following the docs:
https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Process.html#exit/2

```
If pid is trapping exits, the exit signal is transformed into a message {:EXIT, from, reason} and delivered to the message queue of pid.

If reason is the atom :kill, that is if Process.exit(pid, :kill) is called, an untrappable exit signal is sent to pid which will unconditionally exit with reason :killed.
```

So.. somehow I managed to make it work in reverse, :exit triggers handle_info but :not_kill_reason doesn´t :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make an effort to provide a working example.

When you call `Example.kill/0`, it is killing the calling process, not your GenServer.